# Magento Sales Rules Dropdown Missing after upgrade

Tags: magento

Similar to: [Magento Upgrade Issue 1.5.1.0 to 1.9.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146605/magento-upgrade-issue-1-5-1-0-to-1-9-2-1)

I have the following (encountering as I'm upgrading from 1.7.0.2 to 1.8.1.0 in a dev site - also had it going straight to 1.9)

```
a:5:{i:0;s:96:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'rule.calculate_subtotal' in 'field list'";i:1;s:4835:"    0 /domains/[hidden]/dev/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):         Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
1 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
2 /domains/[hidden]/dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
3 /domains/[hidden]/dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
4 /domains/[hidden]/dev/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
5 /domains/[hidden]/dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
6 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Resource/Calculation.php(358): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
7 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Resource/Calculation.php(99): Mage_Tax_Model_Resource_Calculation->_getRates(Object(Varien_Object))
8 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php(264): Mage_Tax_Model_Resource_Calculation->getRateInfo(Object(Varien_Object))
9 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php(509): Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation->getRate(Object(Varien_Object))
10 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php(523): Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation->_getRates(Object(Varien_Object), 'product_class_i...', 'PRODUCT')
11 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Helper/Data.php(466): Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation->getRatesForAllProductTaxClasses(Object(Varien_Object))
12 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Helper/Data.php(448): Mage_Tax_Helper_Data->_getAllRatesByProductClass(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Store))
13 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/js.phtml(45): Mage_Tax_Helper_Data->getAllRatesByProductClass(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Store))
14 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/domains/hidden…’)
15 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
16 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
17 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
18 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
19 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
20 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
21 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
22 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('js', true)
23 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(82): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('js')
24 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/domains/a8uk.c...')
25 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
26 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
27 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
28 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
29 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
30 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
31 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
32 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->editAction()
33 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
34 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
35 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
36 /domains/[hidden]/dev/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
37 /domains/[hidden]/dev/index.php(87): Mage::run('english', 'website')
38 {main}";s:3:"url";s:85:"/index.php/console/catalog_product/edit/id/4965/key/4d7a4458accfaccf439e4b946771a857/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

I believe this is the same situation and tried the attached fix, any other ideas?

Regards,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

After exhausting most options, I found a module from a theme that caused this.

It wasn't apparent as the module xml was combined with other modules named "All.xml", I disable the one relating to Tax and the Tax dropdown reappeared.

So hope this helps someone else